# после нажатия на картинку открыть её описание. html,css,js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Допустим есть много много картинок (около 5000штук) и после нажатия одной из них открыватся модальное окно с описанием этой картинки.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn[0].onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
//обрати внимание на индексы [N] 
span[0].onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "none";
}
//=========================================================
// мои изменения
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn[1].onclick = function() {
  modal[1].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[1].onclick = function() {
  modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
//==========================================
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myBtn"><img src='000948.png' title=' ' style='position:absolute; left:345px;   top:245px' ></a><div  class="modal myModal"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><span class="close">×</span><h2>Интересные факты об этом...</h2></div><div class="modal-body"><p></p></div></div></div>

<a href="#" class="myBtn"><img src='000948.png' title=' ' style='position:absolute; left:375px;   top:245px' ></a><div  class="modal myModal"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><span class="close">×</span><h2>Интересные факты об этом...</h2></div><div class="modal-body"><p></p></div></div></div>
```

### как должно выглядеть ##[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался реализовать это, но происходит проблема с id (если много картинок, то они не открываются). Возможно ли это реализовать при помощи галереи фотографий?

**красные квадраты - сами картинки. после нажатия на одну из картинок открывается модальное окно поверх всех картинок с описанием выбранной картинки.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самую стремачную галерею придумал

На jQuery вешаем tabindex на все картинки и при клике центрируем

> смотреть на весь экран

```js
var elem = $("img");

elem.attr("tabindex", "-1");

elem.click(function() {
  $(".galarea").toggleClass("o")
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.galerea {
  width: 80%;
  max-width:600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  transition: .4s;
}

img:focus {
  width:250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 200px #000;
}

.o {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="galerea">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccc000" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/ccccc0" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/red" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/cc0000" alt="">

</div>
```

Вывод текста из data,с ответом помогли [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/531986)

```js
$(".item").attr("tabindex", "-1");

$('.item img').each((i, el) => {
  const $img = $(el)
  $img.parent().attr('data-caption', $img.attr('data-caption'))
})
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.item:focus:after {
  content: attr(data-caption);
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/ff000" data-caption="некое описание  красной фото" alt="image1" />
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/ccc000" data-caption="некое описание  жёлтой фото" alt="image1" />

</div>
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы картинка не приближалась, а открывалось описание (текст) картинки. А в целом очень красиво выглядет)

Comment: ну механизм тот же ... только при клике открываем не картинку а текст хоть из data хоть из title , откуда угодно

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста как это сделать (взять текст из data) и вывести. (если хочешь, то можешь изменить мой код или свой)  :-)

Comment: если до утра ни кто не подскажет ....то я  сделаю ...ок???

Comment: Спасибки:)))))))

Comment: @roharrim2016  добавил как обещал

Comment: Просто для информации: в jQuery есть выделенный интерфейс для работы с data-атрибутами: `$img.data('caption')`

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо буду знать но мне так было лучше ... покажите этот вариант плиз .. в песочнице

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, из-за css Вам это не особо подходит. Разрешите поинтересоваться? Если Вы "всю ночь просидели" над вопросом копирования атрибута - почему не задали вопрос здесь? Почему в итоге отдали предпочтение другому ресурсу?

Comment: @vp_arth я раньше здесь был зареган под другим именем и тоже с большой кармой , я забыл пароль и логин и вот тогда три года назад я уже задавал этот вопрос за который у меня сняли -110 что ли я не помню точно ...но про всю ночь конечно соврал ..так как tooltip от jquery имеет аналогичный код ... но я скажу так ещё что я не профи и все мои ответы здесь это просто Хобби

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне кажется, что здесь у нас всё можно решить - аккауты можно попробовать объединить, а заминусованный вопрос(почти всегда) - удалить. По поводу хобби - это оно для всех тут так. :)